# Wikipedia API - Returning coordinates for some pages and not others?

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

For instance, the following page has the coordinates at the top of the page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=5839303

and I am able to retrieve them via the API

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=coordinates&pageids=5839303

However this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=56846583

Has the coordinates in an infobox and not at the top of the page. I am unable to retrieve them via the API:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=coordinates&pageids=56846583

Does anyone know why this behaviour occurs and whether it's possible to retrieve the coordinates from my second example via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[prop=coordinates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#prop=coordinates), by default, only returns the primary coordinate of the page. Try adding `coprimary=all` to your query:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=coordinates&pageids=56846583&coprimary=all

Answer (score 0):

**Only 10 coordinates are returned, even if your wider query requests more than 10 search results**

[Documentation for the coordinates parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcoordinates)

For example, if you were trying to perform a geographical search and you've set the `ggslimit` limit to 20, to retrieve up to 20 results; you also need to set the `colimit` to 20, otherwise you will only get coordinates returned for the first default 10 results.

**Example query**

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?prop=coordinates&generator=geosearch&action=query&ggslimit=20&coprimary=all&ggscoord=35.6761919%7C139.6503106&ggsradius=2000&format=json&colimit=20